# How Can I lock cells in Excel based on the value of another?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

For instance, I have a Cell G4 with a drop down list of 1,2, and 4. I want to lock out cells in row 9 based on the choice in G4. For example, if the user selects “1” as the value for G4, I want them to only be able to change the value of cell G9, and lock cells H9, I9, and J9, setting them to a value of “0” if possible. And then were you to change the value of G4 to “2” it would then unlock cell H9 but leave I9 and J9 locked, with those two only unlocking if the value “4” is selected in cell G4.

I have tried different methods using data validation that have not achieved the desired result. I have also tried a few different VBA codes that have also not yielded the desired result.

Comment: You need to tag VBA, since that's required to get what you want

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9g4gMWQx3yfJcxl_5Aw?e=iMriFm)/screenshot/links refer:

**1. Set up**

- All cells except G4 are locked - see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lock-cells-to-protect-them-cb7835f6-9c37-4161-bb53-d1c410acaf21)
- Sheet protected pw=1234, 'select locked and unlocked cells' - see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6)
- Cell G4 with validation list '0,1,2,3' see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b)

---

**2. VBA code**

- Open VB, in project explorer select sheet 1 and paste following code

[image: Sheet1 - Project explorer]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'https://www.teachexcel.com/excel-tutorial/run-a-macro-when-a-specific-cell-changes-in-excel_1592.html#method1
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G4")) Is Nothing Then
        Call locks
    End If
End Sub


Sub locks()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="1234"
    Range("G9:J9").Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    which = Range("g4").Value
    Select Case which
        Case 1
            Range("G9").Select
        Case 2
            Range("H9").Select
        Case 3
            Range("I9:J9").Select
    End Select
    
    Selection.Locked = False
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    'ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:="1234"

End Sub
```

---

[image: Sample GIF]